# How to change the sync folder of OneDrive Desktop Application

Tags: windows, windows-8, sync, onedrive

I have installed the OneDrive Desktop App on my Windows 8 machine. During installation, it asks me where is my OneDrive folder and I can select a folder. After that, all the files in that folder I selected will be synced automatically to my OneDrive after I make changes to them.

I want to do this for an existing folder (actually a root directory of one of my drives E:\). So whatever files I put in there will be synced automatically on my OneDrive. The problem is, if I choose E:\ as my OneDrive folder, it will automatically append E:\OneDrive\ after it. Is there any way I can make the root directory as my OneDrive sync folder? I do not want to move everything I have under the OneDrive folder as it would mess up the directory settings on my other programs.

Hack-ish solutions are also accepted as long as any files I in my E:\ drive syncs. By this I mean changing values in my registry, setting environment variables, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**.

OneDrive as you already realize creates a OneDrive subfolder under the location you select. There is no way to designate OneDrive to the root of a hard drive.

You also can not utilize any sort of symlink or junction "trick" to create aliases. OneDrive does not support symlinks nor junctions. Doing so will cause heavy CPU load because OneDrive errors out when it tries to process symlink or junction folders.

Comment: What about createing links or junctions from OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

As a warning, I might suggest you NOT append your entire E: drive to the one drive, but rather choose the exact folders you wish to be availble for your there as well.